# UDP Throughput : Decreasing InterruptThrottleRate in ethernet adapter e1000e.

Tags: linux, networking, udp, cpu-usage

I'm trying to optimize a UDP server which receives about 3,00,000 packets/sec. The problem is CPU usage increases as high as 85% when the server is receiving packets.

One tuning tip was to decrease the `InterruptThrottleRate` thus decreasing the hard interrupts generated per second and thereby decreasing cpu usage (little bit).

I'm using Ubuntu 11.1 (4 Cores, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470S CPU @ 2.90GHz, 8GB , 1000 Mbits/sec Link) with ethernet driver intel e1000e.

The manual suggested to use modprobe to change ethernet settings.

```
modprobe e1000e InterruptThrottleRate=3000,3000,3000
```

But I couldn't see any change in the CPU usage and I'm not even sure the settings were applied successfully.

Previously I tried receive packet steering and IRQ affinity (which did not help much)

My Questions are:

**How to view the existing settings of the network adapter (settings like InterruptThrottleRate) ?**

**Is there any other way to edit the interrupt moderation ?**

**Any other tips to decrease the CPU utilization (Interrupt latency is not a factor) ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Any tuning tips will help in some situations but not in others. Did you do any research if your situation matches the one the tip is for? How much of your CPU usage is in user/kernel mode? If the CPU increase is in user mode, tuning the network card will very probably NOT help anything. `iostat -c`, `netstat -s` and `ethtool`are your friends to find out some of the parameters; also, i'd try to build a very much stripped down version of the server that does nothing than bounce incoming packets. Don't even start to fiddle with your network settings unless that server has >80% kernel CPU usage.

Comment: top shows 32%sy , 27%si rest us%

Answer (score -1):

Try the following boot parameters:

```
e1000e.IntMode=1,1 e1000e.InterruptThrottleRate=3000,3000,3000
```